# Has it just not saved the updates yet for reading them back?

Tags: vbscript, asp-classic, adodb

This is for a matching game on a children’s website, I need to randomize the order of the answers for the questions.  It is on an older server using classic ASP and an Access database.  These lines will be used in the JavaScript code as the order of the answers.  The code seems to work when I look at the database, but what is written to the page on each row is [   "-"   ].  As I said, the database has random numbers and corresponding letters when viewed after the page load.  The code is very basic but I have tried to simplify it as much as possible to find the cause.

```
ID = trim ("0" & Request.QueryString("ID"))
If Not isnumeric(ID) Then Response.Redirect "default.asp"

Set rs = dbcon.Execute ("Delete * FROM tblTemp;")
strSQL = "INSERT INTO tblTemp ( fldQuestion, fldAnswer) "
strSQL = strSQL + "Select fldQuestion, fldAnswer FROM tblQuestions WHERE fldListID=" & ID & ";"
Set rs = dbcon.Execute (strSQL)

Set rs = dbcon.Execute ("Select ID FROM tblTemp;")
While Not rs.EOF
    Randomize
    x = int(rnd * 16000)
    Set rs2 = dbcon2.Execute ("UPDATE tblTemp SET fldOrder = " & x & " WHERE ID = " & rs.fields("ID") & ";")
    rs.MoveNext
Wend

Set rs = dbcon.Execute ("Select ID FROM tblTemp ORDER By fldOrder;")
x = 65
While Not rs.EOF
    Set rs2 = dbcon2.Execute ("UPDATE tblTemp SET fldChar = """ & Chr(x) & """ WHERE ID = " & rs.fields("ID") & ";")
    x = x + 1
    rs.MoveNext
Wend

Set rs = dbcon.Execute ("Select * FROM tblTemp ORDER By fldOrder;")
While Not rs.EOF
    Response.Write "        """ & rs.fields("fldOrder") & "-" & rs.fields("fldChar") & """," & vbcrlf
    rs.MoveNext
Wend
```

Comment: Your using VBscript to randomize and update a table? Could you not just use `ORDER BY RAND()` if you're wanting the database to return results in a random order?

Comment: "Select * FROM tblQuestions WHERE fldListID = 1 ORDER By rand()"  -  
Undefined function 'rand' in expression.

Comment: Also tried using MSAccess function RND, got the response "Either BOF or EOF is True"

Answer (score 0):

If we leave aside the fact of insufficient process, the problem is in making two connections dbcon and dbcon2. Change the last select to dbcon2 and you should get the expected result

```
Set rs = dbcon2.Execute ("Select * FROM tblTemp ORDER By fldOrder;")
```

alternatively, get rid of dbcon2 everywhere as it seems has no big sense.